# Sail up 'laravel.test' docker container Exited with "127"

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, laravel-sail

I tried to set up a docker container for this project but every time I run `./vendor/bin/sail up -d`, the `laravel.test` container exits with "127".

The rest of the containers work just fine.

[image: Sail up -d on windows 10 with WSL]

At first, I thought this might've been WSL having an issue on Windows for me so I created an Ubuntu VM through VirtualBox and did the same process but the result was the exact same:

[image: Sail up -d on Ubuntu]

And because of this, running `localhost:4000` or `192.168.99.100:4000` on a web browser displays nothing....

Other info in case it might be linked somehow:

- I previously tried to run `./vendor/bin/sail up -d` but I ran into [this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uGYo.jpg). And the only way I was able to bypass it and get to where I am now is changing my `.env` file's EOL from `CRLF` to `LF` through VS Code.
- When I open Docker's Windows app's `laravel.test` container, [it displays this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpqbE.jpg).

I am pretty stumped on how to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Apologies if I've made any mistakes as this is my first time with Laravel-Sail and Docker.

HERE IS MY `docker-compose` FILE:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${APP_PORT_OCTANE:-8080}:8080'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:${MEILISEARCH_BUILD:-latest}'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-meilisearch:/data.ms'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://localhost:7700/health"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    myadmin:
        image: 'phpmyadmin:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_PHP_MYADMIN_PORT:-8080}:80'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            UPLOAD_LIMIT: 300M
        links:
            - "mysql:db"
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
    sail-meilisearch:
        driver: local
```

Comment: can you share your docker file and docker-compose file?

Comment: @gguney I've updated the post with the `docker-compose` file at the bottom.


As for the Docker file, where can I access it from? Windows and/or Ubuntu.

Comment: Does your 80 port is available or 8080? Can you change APP_PORT inside your .env file to something else like 82, 83 etc. And can you change myadmin container port too? 8080 is clashing I guess

Comment: @gguney Changed up both and result was the same unfortunately. 80 or 8080 wasn't in use. But I changed to something else from what was there to test it out, but result was all the same.

Comment: Can you run sail without - d option and track the this container's output? It should return some information about the problem

Comment: @gguney Doing that, the container gets: `wdc-second-option-laravel.test-1  | /usr/bin/env: 'bash\r': No such file or directory` and it then exits with code 127

Answer (score -2):

This configuration should solve the problem:
[image: screenshot of proposed configuration]

Comment: Please add a textual description for the content of your picture. Not everybody can benefit from picture-only solutions. Feel free to correct my choice of "config", which I am not very sure about (a reason to add more description).